# Which emergency food for backpacking (meat-like Granola bar?)

Tags: food-and-drink, emergencies

I will be travelling for a couple of days to remote regions of Laos.

I would like to take some kind of "emergency" food if nothing is around (or nothing trustworthy).

People with a sweet tooth have the perfect solution: Granola bars. But I really don't like them - pretty much like any of this swee-ish stuff.

Things like dried sausages or Beef jerky goes the right direction but it lacks carbs - particularly some form of bread - without that I still feel hungry and these things do not work.

There are some things that include crackers (tuna salad or chicken salad) but crackers are too salty, to less carbs (same as chips) and set up my stomache rather than feeling full afterwards.

In Germany there are things like Pumpernickel: This (**together** with some sausage) would come close: It can be densely packed, exists even in canned (in military) has high energy and you feel full afterwards. The problem is that US people don't like it that much so it's hard to get in the US (particularly in small packages, not to mention canned version).

Most ideal would be some pizza-, burrito-, sausage- whatever stuff that is highly densely packed, durable and available.

What I'd be looking for would have the following properties:

- Savory taste: Pizza, burrito, Burger, Hot Dog etc but also Salami
- Readily available in the US
- Nothing that requires preparation or hot water
- Includes bread or at least some meaningful carbs
- Is densely and **seperately** packed (each portion), like a granola bar
- Is durable and good for a long time, even in hot or wet conditions (like canned food)

Any idea if something like this exists?

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic here, but you may find more specific expertise at [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I never found myself in danger of starving in Laos. Especially because anywhere remote enough to be devoid of people had way too many unexploded landmines from the Vietnam War to actually be wandering about in....

Comment: take a look at unsalted peanut: 25% carbs, 25% protein, 50% fat by weight. High in fiber too and about 6 calories per gram

Comment: You could always make a batch of [hardtack](http://www.americantable.org/2013/06/civil-war-recipe-hardtack-1861/) to take with you.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to make your own sandwiches.
Buy pilot bread (a from of hard tack), party bread or Mestemacher bread (comes in many varieties) for your carbs and shelf stable salami and/or pepperoni for your meat.
All five are readily available in grocery stores and Amazon.

Make your sandwiches with no other additions or condiments.
First wrap them well individually in plastic wrap, then aluminum foil, then place 4 to 6 them in a small ziplock, repeat as needed. Then place all ziplocks into a larger ziplock.

Keep out of direct sunlight.

Comment: +1 from me.  I'm definitely getting insights into the life of a professional limo driver from reading some of your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I used to carry around a **dark chocolate bar** and a **can of tuna** in my backpacking days.

- Dark chocolate is energy-packed and not sweet, especially if you opt for 80-90% cocoa, although this can be an acquired taste!
- Tuna can be eaten on its own in a pinch, but I usually used it for a simple sandwich.  As a former French colony, you can get a pretty decent baguette almost anywhere in Laos, and they're quite "trustworthy" too: if it's not visibly moldy, it'll be safe to eat.